# Can't set image upload variable to NULL

Tags: php, mysql, image, null, upload

So weird well annoying problem, I'm trying to upload images from a form (all works fine) However when there is no image it should set itself to NULL, but because i'm using $target_dir . basename  it keeps taking the last part of the $target_dir instead of setting to NULL and inserting the word products into the database instead of nothing. But obv need the $target_dir for when the upload takes place to put in correct place. Please see code below, all help much appreciated.

```
$target_dir = "../images/products/";


      if (!isset ($_FILES["img1"]["name"])) {
        $target_file1 = NULL;
      } else {
        $target_file1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img1"]["name"]);
          }

          if (!isset ($_FILES["img2"]["name"])) {
            $target_file2 = NULL;
          } else {
            $target_file2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img2"]["name"]);
          }

          if (!isset ($_FILES["img3"]["name"])) {
            $target_file3 = NULL;
          } else {
            $target_file3 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img3"]["name"]);
          }

          if (!isset ($_FILES["img4"]["name"])) {
            $target_file4 = NULL;
          } else {
            $target_file4 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img4"]["name"]);
          }
```

SQL query and relevant info

```
<pre>
$image1 = basename($target_file1);
$image2 = basename($target_file2);
$image3 = basename($target_file3);
$image4 = basename($target_file4);

echo $image1;
echo $image2;
echo $image3;
echo $image4;

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (product_code, product_name, category, 
filter, description, specification, img1, img2, img3, img4, price) 
VALUES('$product_code', '$product_name', '$category', '$filter', 
'$description', '$specification', '$image1', '$image2', '$image3', 
'$image4', '$price')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
              ?>
</pre>
```

K, changed it to set the values first and only assign value if isset

same thing, see screenshot of output below.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your SQL call too, cant see much of a problem with what you have given.

Comment: when i take $target_dir out of the equation it leaves the mysql value Null but doesn't upload the image to the directory

Comment: You can try to define them as null before if statements actually and add a validation before inserting. So if they are isset you add value to your target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try

```
$target_dir = "../images/products/";


if (!isset ($_FILES["img1"]["name"])) {
    $target_file1 = NULL;
} else {
    if (!empty($_FILES["img1"]["name"])) {
        $target_file1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img1"]["name"]);
    } else {
        $target_file1 = NULL;
    }
}

if (!isset ($_FILES["img2"]["name"])) {
    $target_file2 = NULL;
} else {
    if (!empty($_FILES["img2"]["name"])) {
        $target_file2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img2"]["name"]);
    } else {
        $target_file2 = NULL;
    }
}

if (!isset ($_FILES["img3"]["name"])) {
    $target_file3 = NULL;
} else {
    if (!empty($_FILES["img3"]["name"])) {
        $target_file3 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img3"]["name"]);
    } else {
        $target_file3 = NULL;
    }
}

if (!isset ($_FILES["img4"]["name"])) {
    $target_file4 = NULL;
} else {
    if (!empty($_FILES["img4"]["name"])) {
        $target_file4 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img4"]["name"]);
    } else {
        $target_file4 = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you thank you thank you worked like a charm.  now i just have to figure out how i broke the actual upload of the image lol.